# How to find expected value from cumulative distribution function?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, sampling, function

[image]

Hello everyone, I'm currently doing research based on the model in Competitive fit-revelation sampling and mixed pricing strategy (Wu &Deng, 2021). And I don't understand how they can conclude the expected value of price based on the cumulative distribution function as in pic. Please help me out. Knowing that s,h,V,c are real numbers that > 0.

Comment: $E[X] = \int x dF(x)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value

Comment: If $X$ is positive, $$\mathbb E[X]=\int_0^\infty [1-F(x)]\,\text d x$$(*Hint:* Try to simplify the definition of the cdfs by removing most parameters.)

Comment: Since the CDF defines the distribution, *of course* it determines the expectation.  The preceding two comments supply two out of very many different ways to express and compute the expectation.

Comment: Thanks for all your advice, however, I did try the above formula E(X) but was still unable to figure out why inside logarithm is (s+h)/h